# How do I check if there is an already running dask scheduler?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I want to start a local cluster from python with a specific number of workers, and then connect a client to it.

```
cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=8, ip='127.0.0.1')
client = Client(cluster)
```

But before, I want to check if there is an existing local cluster, started for example by the dask-scheduler command. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no standard convention to check if a scheduler exists on your machine.  The best you can do is try with a short timeout.  The default port is 8786

```
from dask.distributed import Client, TimeoutError

try:
    client = Client('tcp://localhost:8786', timeout='2s')
except TimeoutError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I am looking for!